# AnimatorSet stopping when playing sequentially

Tags: java, android-studio, android-animation, objectanimator, animatorset

I have some code which creates a list of points called path.

Here is a sample list: [[1, 3], [2, 3], [2, 4]]

Here is the code I wrote to animate movement to these points sequentially:

```
        ArrayList<Animator> movements = new ArrayList<>();
        int prevY = start[1];
        int prevX = start[0];
        for (int[] square : path) {

            ObjectAnimator motion = new ObjectAnimator();

            float[] coord = screenFromGrid(square[0], square[1], gridSizeY);
            long speed = (long) (6000.0 / this.displayMetrics.widthPixels);
            speed = (long) (speed * getSquareSize(gridSizeY));

            if (square[0] != prevX) {

                motion = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this.sprite1, "x", coord[0]);
                motion.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                motion.setDuration(speed);
                movements.add(motion);
                prevX = square[0];
            } else if (square[1] != prevY) {

                motion = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this.sprite1, "y", coord[1]);
                motion.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                motion.setDuration(speed);
                movements.add(motion);
                prevY = square[1];
            }
        }
        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animatorSet.playSequentially(movements);
        animatorSet.start();
```

The problem is that animation completely stops in the middle without throwing any error.

I checked the debugger and it says all the animations have been stored properly.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I know from experience is, that AnimatorSet is buggy, and does not always work as expected, I have also had my issues with it, and luckily found another, better approach :
[ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator) is a nice way to animate Views with short and concise code. You could write your own method which you can modify and reuse as wanted, something like :

```
private void customAnimation(View view, float toX, float toY, int duration, boolean loop) {
    view.animate()
        .translationX(toX)
        .translationY(toY)
        .setDuration(duration)
        .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator())
        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                if(loop) {
                    customAnimation(..., false);
                }
            }
        });
```

The listener waits for the first animation to finish, so you can call the next animation there. To play sequentially without looping forever I have added a boolean to the parameters which only executes the next animation if true.

That would also shorten the rest of your code to something like this :

```
int prevY = start[1];
int prevX = start[0];
for (int[] square : path) {
    float[] coord = screenFromGrid(square[0], square[1], gridSizeY);
    long speed = (long) (6000.0 / this.displayMetrics.widthPixels);
    speed = (long) (speed * getSquareSize(gridSizeY));

    if (square[0] != prevX) {
        customAnimation(this.sprite1, coord[0], 0, speed, true);
        prevX = square[0];
    } else if (square[1] != prevY) {
        customAnimation(this.sprite1, 0, coord[1], speed, true);
        prevY = square[1];
    }
}
```

Be sure to check the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator) for all available methods, maybe [.translationXBy(float byX)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator#translationXBy(float)) is more suited in your case than [.translationX(float toX)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator#translationX(float))

Comment: Thank you so much!

I have one question: You said to call the customAnimation twice.
Did you mean like this?

`customAnimation(...)`

`customAnimation(...)`

If so, that didn't work for me and I tried to write a recursive function using withEndAction but that didn't work either.
How do I play sequentially?

Comment: sry I misinterpretated the word sequentially, I updated my answer

Comment: Thank you :)
I have one last question: here you say next animation, but how do I loop this dynamically without a recursion?

Comment: you could add a Boolean to the parameters which if true, the customAnimation is called if not it stops...

Comment: what I mean is how can I dynamically play the animations one after the other.
Because it looks to me like I have to hard code each sequential animation.

Comment: Updated my answer, this is only one way to do it and should get you started

Comment: Thank you so so so much!